how do I import a .csv file in graphdb for ontorefine? I don't see how to open ontorefine in workbench mode?
I read the manual about importing a .csv file into ontorefine in workbench mode, but I don't how to do this.   All I see is the option to import in rdf mode.   What am I missing?
I created a graphdb repository and wanted to import into a project with ontorefine, but couldn't find any option that matched the documentation.

Hi there, can you share the versions of the GraphDB and Ontotext Refine that you are using? Also, a link to the documentation that you are referring to, would be helpful.

From your comment, I assume you are reading documentation for old version of GraphDB (prior 10.x.x). The newer versions of GraphDB doesn't contain the Refine part, it is now separate free product. More info GDB 10.0.0. Here is a page from where you can download or read about the Ontotext Refine.
